# P0f log reader 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, logging

I wrote a script to read and grab data from P0f.log. No problem at first but when i ran it on Ubuntu 12.04 it says 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'.

Here's my code

```
import os
import re
import string

def readlog(config):
    logfile = open(config['path'])
    log = logfile.readlines()
    logfile.close()
    lines = []
    data = []

    for line in log:
        lines.append(line)
    for strip in lines:
        m = re.search('(?<=cli=)[a-zA-Z0-9_ .:]+', strip)
        n = re.search('(?<=os=)[a-zA-Z0-9_ .:]+', strip)
        ip = m.group(0)
        if n:
            os = n.group(0)
        else:
            os = "null"
        datax = "_".join([ip, os])
        data1 = datax.split("_", 2)
        data.append(data1)

    return data
```

I need to know whether it's a Python or I'm doing it wrong (but it ran perfectly on Arch Linux); this is Python version 2.7.8.

Comment: The problem is likely `ip = m.group(0)` - you do not check whether m is set, so it might be None if the regex did not match.

Comment: Hint: What happens if the file has an empty line?